# Android Fragments over layout inflation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know that fragments are used for making flexible UIs. But I was once asked that what is the advantage of using fragment over layout inflation. In other words we can inflate our custom layout file(one that we inflate for representing fragment UI) into the container layout of the backing activity. So why to use fragments instead?

In my opinion fragments are used over layout inflation for better designing purpose as it has its own lifecycle methods. Can anyone give me a better answer for this.

Comment: The Fragments vs. Views discussion is nothing new. You may find the [this](https://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/advocating-against-android-fragments.html) and interesting read, and also have a look at libraries inspired by that blog post, i.e. [this one](http://mattlogan.me/making-pancakes-an-alternative-to-fragmentmanager-for-views.html) that was published only days ago.

Answer (score 3):

Fragments intercept Activity's lifecycle events (onCreate(), onStart(), onResume(), etc). Because of it Fragments can save and resume their state and data when your Activity is destroyed and then recreated.
So you may not save the data of your UI, when a user rotate his phone. Fragment does it for you.

Also Fragments are useful when you want to separate your UI into some units.

And with Fragments you may create your own class that builds in Activity's lifecycle.

Of course you may do the same without Fragments, but I believe that Google developed Fragments in order to improve our life and increase efficiency of our working.

Comment: Does a fragment allow the layout/views to be freed from memory by the garbage collection?  With inflating layouts, I can do `parent.removeAllViews()` to save memory, then inflate later on when I want the views back.  How do fragments compare to this memory-wise?